# Hide certain tags on Product Edit tag cloud

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi on my site I now have over 800 different product tags. When adding products it takes a very long time to scroll through them all to tag them. I tried to target specific product tags in css and display none but it wasn't working. Ideally I'd like to only show a specific 30 tags and omit the rest from the "choose the most used tag box. This is what I have so far. I know I'm close. If anyone could offer some direction. It would be greatly appreciated

```
#tagcloud-product_tag > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child(n + x)` selector to target all elements after x number. So in you example use `:nth-child(n + 30)` so every child after 30th will be affected. Here is modified code:

```
#tagcloud-product_tag > ul > li:nth-child(n + 30) {display: none !important;}
```

Here you can see example of using :nth-child(n+10) to affect all elements after 10th - https://jsfiddle.net/pbnu346d/